# how can change the jquery thick box title dynamically?

Tags: jquery

how can set the title of jquery thick box dynamically and how to resize the thick box by js

any idea please share

Comment: how do you want to change the title? add more information

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for 
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0):

u can use JS or Jquery for assigning value for title in that div, after that u have to show/open that  thickbox...

u can look at  the following code to give title for the div dynamically,

```
<div id="text1" title="A bold text">Hello my friends!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(text1).title="New tooltip"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) since the plugin owners itself are recommending other alternatives

> While Thickbox had its day, it is not
>   maintained any longer, so we recommend
>   you use some alternatives

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) out! and let us know the problem you faced

well you haven't tell me exactly what you need (inline frame, or iframe with external page or slide show or picture). if you are looking for external iframe then you can try this one

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
    });
</script>
<h1>ColorBox Demonstration</h1>
<p><a class='example7' href="http://google.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
```

Comment: When the thickbox poped up, the title is "new window"
 ie used this <a title='new window' href='example.php?height=300&width=300'> 
After this i  click the link in thick box that will load new page in thickbox itself ,
then i need to change the title of page "new window " to "old window" with size 400X550